# How to add watermark image in all pages using codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, watermark, alternate

i want to add a watermark image to all php pages that should be fixed at center .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/wstyle.css">
```

wstyle.css file

```
body {
   background-image: url('../images/anna.png');
   background-size: auto;   
}
```

image not loaded in my page. how to solve it? any alternate method is available?

Comment: Hi @anbesivam and welcom to StackOverflow. This could be caused by numerious issues. Try starting out by keeping it simple; add the ˋbackgroundˋ styles in a style attribute on your ˋ<body>ˋ element and verify if that works. Then move it up step by step by moving it to an inline stylesheet and finally to an external stylesheet file. Happy coding!

Comment: i think you need to specify width

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/wstyle.css">
```

wstyle.css

```
body {
background: url(../images/anna.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: auto;}
```

for all pages
create new file in view **header.php** put that code in this file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/wstyle.css">
```

call **header.php** in all your controllers

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function index() {
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('home');
}
}

?>
```

Comment: working superb. but the image shows original file. not able to set brightness in picture manager.  how to set a image as watermark in css